# why colour of CuSO4 and CuCl3 is different?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, color

These two are simple ionic compounds , not complexes [if I do not consider water of hydration] then how can I rationalise the difference in colour?

Comment: Cu3+ is still a different color than Cu2+, isn't it?

Comment: @Lighthart Honestly, I've never seen copper(III) in solution. Have you? It's not that copper(III) wouldn't exist, such as in ores, but as a naked, solvated cation?

Comment: Do you really mean $\ce{CuCl3}$ or is it just a typo and you thought in $\ce{CuCl2}$? On a second note, copper(II)sulfate itself undergoes a colour change when converting the pentahydrate to the anhydrous form.

Comment: LIGAND FIELD THEORY.  Colors in these ions are based on electron transitions between non-degenerate d-orbitals. The energy of these transitions (thus the color) is a function of the metal oxidation state, the type of ligand/counterion, and the molecular geometry. Hydration or not d-orbitals are still going to distort based on those factors.